Авто замена сессии на pyrogram
Нужно сделать так, что бы после выполнения определенных условий (в моем случае это получение определенного сообщения от нужного юзера), автоматически заменялась сессия, то есть что бы юзер-бот автоматически пересаживался на другую учетную запись используя файл .session
то есть не запрашивая код подтверждения.
Возможно ли это реализовать и каким образом?
